# CSS file loads but inactive

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make a static version of:

http://www.streetscenes.org.uk

here:

http://www.streetscenes.org.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

It's all in order, everything links and loads including the css file, but the css is not being applied. I've checked Chrome dev tools Network loading data for clues, but it seems to access the css file fine. Any ideas?

One thing I should say is that upon transferring the files, S3 marked the file type as `binary/octet-stream` so the file downloaded when opening it in the source window, which I rectified, then cleared cache, etc.

Comment: looks like someone it link building

Comment: Could you explain? I don't follow.

Comment: you not suppose to put links to a website on here. you need to show the code or a jsfiddle link so we can see the code working

Comment: ok, i'll amend right away

Comment: Sorry, i got right answer before getting chance to add fiddle, etc. Please forgive if I leave it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the network inspector closely, you will notice that the CSS file is served with:

> Content-Type: text/plain

The browser downloads the file but does not display it because of incorrect content type. Correct the content type (should be `text/css`) and the CSS will display.

Answer (score 1):

Now change your css `href`   link

```
href="wp-content/themes/best/style.css%3Fver=1"
```

**into this**

```
href="http://www.streetscenes.org.uk/wp-content/themes/best/style.css?ver=1"
```

**as like this**

[image]

[image]